# Connect to sybase IQ with dbisql pop the error The DISPLAY environment variable is not set

Tags: database, sap-iq, isql

My purpose is connect to Sybase IQ with dbisql

- OS:Linux XIYL50837198A 3.0.101-84-default #1 SMP Tue Oct 18 10:32:51 UTC 2016 (15251d6) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

- My sybase IQ version is 16-1

- My installation information:

1. install set: typical
2. licence type:  evaluate
3. HTTP Port 4282
4. HTTPS Port 4283
5. RMI Port 4992
6. TDS Port 4998

Before connecting I export all the environment variable as all as I can and  start the demo Database with setting the user and password.

```
cd iq

export IQDIR16=/sapmnt/home/I331922/iq/IQ-16_1
export IQ=/sapmnt/home/I331922/iq/IQ-16_1
export SYBASE=/sapmnt/home/I331922/iq
export PATH=$PATH:/sapmnt/home/I331922/iq/IQ-16_1/bin64

source SYBASE.env
csh SYBASE.csh
source SYBASE.sh
cd /sapmnt/home/I331922/iq/IQ-16_1

csh IQ-16_1.csh
source IQ-16_1.sh
cd ..
source IQ.sh
csh IQ.csh
cd /sapmnt/home/I331922/iq/IQ-16_1/demo
ls

adata  demodata  dqpdata.sql  dqpquery.sql  mkasiqdemo.sql  mkiqdemo.sh  mkiqdemo.sql
./mkiqdemo.sh -absolute -dba demo -pwd password
start_iq @iqdemo.cfg iqdemo.db


cd /sapmnt/home/I331922/iq/IQ-16_1/bin64
./dbisql -c 'uid=demo;pwd=password;eng=XIYL50837198A_iqdemo;links=tcpip'
```

Then I use the command

```
dbisql -c 'uid=demo;pwd=password;eng=XIYL50837198A_iqdemo;links=tcpip'
```

pop the error

> **The DISPLAY environment variable is not set. It must be set for Interactive SQL to operate correctly.**

Then I use this

```
dbisql -c "uid=demo,pwd=password,eng=XIYL50837198A_iqdemo,links=tcpip" -port 4998 -host 10.56.177.237
```

this

```
dbisql -c "uid=demo,pwd=password,eng=XIYL50837198A_iqdemo,links=tcpip" -port 4998
```

this

```
dbisql -c "uid=demo,pwd=password,eng=XIYL50837198A_iqdemo,links=tcpip" -port 4998 -host 10.56.177.237 -datasource dsn
```

It constantly give me the same error message.

Can everyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved
Because the dbisql need the XGUI. and the simple way is use dbisqlc inst